# KaToolin just seems to have this unique key hardcoded to work, how can we tell if it is legitimately tied back to the authentic Kali project?

Tags: python, security, ubuntu, kali-linux

So line 53 of katoolin.py has this hardcoded value:

```
cmd1 = os.system("apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6")
```

How can we verify that ED444FF07D8D0BF6 tracks back to the authentic project?

This seems like the better way to add the repo keys:

```
wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_2018.2_all.deb
apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_2018.1_all.deb
```

Where https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/ is where you go to find the latest keyring .deb.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this by using the following steps.

1. Open the URL http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/ in your browser.
2. Type in the Key ID 0xED444FF07D8D0BF6 in the search box , select the option "Get Regular Index of matching Keys"

[image]

3. Click Search and you should see the following result

[image]

Alternately you may want to craft this url and post it in your browser

http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0xED444FF07D8D0BF6&op=index